# String UTF-8 conversion Issue

Tags: java

I am encountering an issue in String conversion to UTF-8. Basically, i have developed a DayDescriptionEnum which will actually, get the day of week and return description accordingly. Kindly see the below code.

```
public enum DayDescriptionEnum {

    SUNDAY(1, "Sunday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u0623\\u062d\\u062f"),
    MONDAY(2, "Monday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u0625\\u062b\\u0646\\u064a\\u0646"),
    TUESDAY(3, "Tuesday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u062b\\u0644\\u0627\\u062b\\u0627\\u0621"),
    WEDNESDAY(4, "Wednesday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u0623\\u0631\\u0628\\u0639\\u0627\\u0621"),
    THURSDAY(5, "Thursday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u062e\\u0645\\u064a\\u0633"),
    FRIDAY(6, "Friday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u062c\\u0645\\u0639\\u0629"),
    SATURDAY(7, "Saturday", "\\u0627\\u0644\\u0633\\u0628\\u062a");

    private long dayofWeek;
    private String dayDescriptionEnglish;
    private String dayDescriptionArabic;

    private DayDescriptionEnum(long dayofWeek, String dayDescriptionEnglish, String dayDescriptionArabic) {
        this.dayofWeek = dayofWeek;
        this.dayDescriptionEnglish = dayDescriptionEnglish;
        this.dayDescriptionArabic = dayDescriptionArabic;
    }

    public long getDayofWeek() {
        return dayofWeek;
    }

    public String getDayDescriptionEnglish() {
        return dayDescriptionEnglish;
    }

    public String getDayDescriptionArabic() {

        return dayDescriptionArabic;
    }
}


  public static DayDescriptionEnum getDescriptionOfDay(long dayOfWeek){
        DayDescriptionEnum dayDescriptionEnum = DayDescriptionEnum.SUNDAY;

        if(PermitReportConstants.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.SUNDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.MONDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.MONDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.TUESDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.WEDNESDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.THURSDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.FRIDAY;
        }

        if(PermitReportConstants.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek){
            dayDescriptionEnum =  DayDescriptionEnum.SATURDAY;
        }

        return dayDescriptionEnum;
    }
```

The above method takes day of week and returns the Enum accordingly. Now when i am displaying this string, its showing description as "\u0627\u0644\u0623\u062d\u062f" same. I researched and realized i need to convert the String into UTF-8 format. So i put the code below as

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = null ;
        try {
             utf8Bytes = dayDescriptionEnum.getDayDescriptionArabic().getBytes("UTF-8");
            String arabicDescription = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF-8");
            readyToPrintDeliver.setContractDayDescAr(arabicDescription);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
```

Still no effect. My question is, i had already converted the string to unicode. Where am i making a mistake? Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: You have double blackslashes in your string which means that you escape your second backslash with the first one and your unicode characters are not recognized. Use only one backslash.

Comment: don't use \\ , just use \. with \\ your are escaping utf

Comment: Why are you converting to UTF-8 and back again to start with?

Comment: Converting to UTF-8 and back again should have no effect for valid characters.  I am glad it didn't change the string.

Comment: Thanks a ton people. It has worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UTF-8 is a red herring here. You don't need to convert to UTF-8 and back *at all* - you just need to fix your strings so that you're not escaping the backslash:

```
SUNDAY(1, "Sunday", "\u0627\u0644\u0623\u062d\u062f"),
// etc
```

Within a string literal, `\\` is used for the backslash character - so in your original code, the strings genuinely contained backslashes, `u` characters, and hex digits... the *only* thing that was an escape sequence was the `\\` repeatedly. You don't want that - you just want the Unicode characters, using `\uXXXX` as a Unicode escape sequence.

With the code above, you don't need to convert at all - just use:

```
readyToPrintDeliver.setContractDayDescAr(dayDescriptionEnum.getDayDescriptionArabic());
```

Comment: My miss. Thanks a lot @Jon. I had the same confusion, i had given the string in UTF-8, why do i need to convert it back. As it was not converting it back, so i did this. Lemme try it back.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. Simply love this place. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most IDEs support UTF-8 encoding.  While using unicode is more portable, being able to type the intended characters natively in your code might be more natural.

```
public enum DayDescriptionEnum {

    SUNDAY(1, "Sunday", "الأحد"),
    MONDAY(2, "Monday", "الإثنين"),
    TUESDAY(3, "Tuesday", "الثلاثاء"),
    WEDNESDAY(4, "Wednesday", "الأربعاء"),
    THURSDAY(5, "Thursday", "الخميس"),
    FRIDAY(6, "Friday", "الجمعة"),
    SATURDAY(7, "Saturday", "السبت");
```

This compiles & runs fine, and if you can read Arabic, it might be easier to work with and check.